# How to Initialize repository and dispose objectcontext with dependency injection when using mutiple projects in a solution

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4, repository-pattern, entity-framework-4.3

I have 4 dll projects in my solution.

1. MVC 4 web app
2. Business Layer
3. Data Access Layer (Implements repository pattern)
4. Domain (referenced in all of the above projects)

I am trying to implement dependency injection for this architecture. Every example I have found explains dependency injection creates an instance of repository in a constructor within controller and calls a dispose method on the repository which in-turn disposes object context which means DAL is directly referenced in web layer. However, I don't want to have this direct reference between the web and DAL instead business should be referenced in web and dal should be referenced in business. WEB -> Business -> DAL.

My question is how do i initialize repository and dispose objectcontext with the above approach? Do I need to create interfaces for my business classes as well and use them instead of repository interfaces to inject dependency and then in-turn initialize repository from within a constructor in concrete business class OR should I reference the DAL and BLL both in web layer, initialize repository from within controller's constructor and pass that object to business layer?